# Run-Time Check Failure #0 for run-time recompiling

Tags: c++

I have an exe, a dll and a static lib. Both the exe and dll depends on the lib and the dll will be loaded into the exe in run-time using `LoadLibrary`. Below is a simplified version since the full code is too long.

In `lib`

```
struct base{
  virtual void update() = 0;
};
std::vector<base*> container;
```

In `dll`

```
struct derived : public base {
  void update() override {}
};
//some functions to instantiate derived class and push into container
```

In `exe`

```
int main() {
  while(true) {
    for (const auto & elem : container)
      elem->update(); //keep on updating
  }
}
```

What I want to do is to be able to change derived classes(will be more than one) and be able to run-time load the dll back with the updated stuff.

It works fine until I change what's inside `derived::update()` function and recompile and load back the dll. There is no run-time error if I recompile and load without changing anything.

I've tried to remove all elements inside the container and push back again with the "updated" derived class when I recompile and reload the dll but the error persists. However, there is no run-time error if I just remove all elements inside the container without pushing the new derived class.

The full error text is `Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the only (if not the only) way to do this is to carefully remove all references to the DLL before you unload it.

1. Destroy all the objects in `container` (saving enough appropriate data to reconstruct them later, possibly thru serializaton)
2. Unload the DLL,
3. Load the new DLL (which may be at a different address, and/or the data and functions in it at different offsets)
4. Reconstruct your `container` objects.

Comment: Thanks! It worked when I destroyed all objects in `container` before unloading/loading the dll. However, I'm not sure why there's a difference in destroying the objects before or after unloading/loading of the dll. Would you mind explaining that?

Comment: @Nyque: I believe unloading and destroying afterwards is a contradiction. Unloading while there are still objects depending on the DLL is weird. And destroying after unloading the DLL containing the destructor seems also weird. The only possible way is like 1201ProgramAlarm described.

Comment: Once you unload the DLL, the vtable (holds pointers to the virtual functions) is dangling (pointing at memory that has been freed/deallocated).  Any call to a virtual function after that can be bad.  There's also potential global data (used by the compiler to support the language) issues.  I don't know why you get the error you do instead of a segfault.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm After trying again, this works only when I unload/reload it once and I got the error `Exception thrown: read access violation.` the second time. Any idea why?

Comment: @Nyque You probably still have something referencing the DLL that you're unloading.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm This is sort of unrelated to the question but turns out that the `container` sort of keeps its "state" of the previous one after each reload. At the start, `container` only has 1 object which I destroyed and added 1 new object. However, at the 2nd reload, `container` has 2 objects. I'm sure that it's not the add that's the problem because I have `if (size() == 0)` as the condition. I also checked the size of `container` after I destroy so that shouldn't be the issue too. Do you have any idea what might have caused this?